# Real time circle detection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have written the following program to detect a circle in real time. But it doesn't work.
The compiler doesn't show any error but the problem is that the program doesn't even detect a circle. How can I fix it?
here is my code
using namespace cv;

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("main",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("blur",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Mat img;
    Mat img2;
    int c;
    float radius;

    while(1)
    {
        cap>>img;
        imshow("main",img);

        cvtColor(img,img2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(img2,img2,Size(9,9),2,2);
        imshow("blur",img2);

        vector <Vec3f> circles;
        HoughCircles(img2,circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,img2.rows/8,200,100,0,0);

        for(size_t i=0;i<circles.size();i++)
        {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]),cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);

            circle(img,center,3,Scalar(0,255,0),-1,8,0);

            circle(img,center,radius,Scalar(0,0,255),3,8,0);
        }

        c = waitKey(33);

        if(c==27)
            break;
    }

    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your program, it seems you just forgot to visualize it using `imshow()` after the detection. You only drew the image before the detection, in this way, you were not able to see the circles (maybe this mistakenly make you think there is no circles detected) even it did detect some circles.

Try to add

```
imshow("main", img);
```

right before `c = waitKey(33);`.

You will see the circles if it does detect some circles.

---

**Edit:** to answer your comment for real time circle detection:

Do it in a `while` loop style will make it work for video frames. However, whether it is real time or not depends on how fast `HoughCircles()` will work and also other stuff inside the loop despite you setup the proper time for `waitKey()`.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still didn't work for real time circle detection. However when I tried it by loading an image instead of using the video capture it worked. How can I make it work for real time circle detection